# Modal UIView content doesn't appear till after animation has finished

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a modal UIView dialog that I am using to show a help page. For some reason the contents of the help page (generated programatically) doesn't show until the transition animation has finished.

I currently add the contents to my view in `viewWillAppear`.

How do I render the contents before the animation transition takes place such that the content is in place before the animation?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //add uiwebview control
}
```

Comment: I'm dreaming about your code..

Comment: Why don't you use `loadView` or `viewDidLoad` methods?

Comment: Add the contents to the view in `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: `viewDidLoad` has the same issue.

Comment: `loadView` just made the calling `UIView` hang...

Answer (score 0):

Try presenting your view in `-(void)viewDidAppear` Method

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding your contents in viewDidLoad should work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Here your contents

}
```

Maybe an issue occurs when you show your view modally.

Can you please show this code?

*This is supposed to be a comment, but I'm not allowed to write comments yet.*